# -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError specify memory

Tags: java, performance, jvm

I would like to specify amount of memory used when `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` VM argument is used. Normally, I control the heap size using `-Xmx<size>` VM argument. But when I do that the out of memory error never occurs. Does anybody know a way to specify such a parameter so that when the heap size (or even the stack size) reaches that parameter the out of memory error is thrown and I can get the heap dump?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-Xmx` is the right way to do this along with `-Xss` for the stack size to cause a `StackOverflowException`. If you don't get the expected `OutOfMemoryError` you might need to try lower values for `-Xmx` since the JVM tends to go somewhat beyond that limit before it throws the error and it seems to ignore anything below 15m for `-Xmx`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question more precisely than what was provided by x4u, it would help to know the following:

**Question #1:** When you explicitly set `-Xmx`, what are you setting it to?  What is the difference between the two heap sizes (with and without `-Xmx`).  I'm assuming you're increasing the heap size when you set it explicitly.

**Question #2**: Does your program terminate, or run forever?  If it terminates and you're not seeing the OOM, it could be that you don't have a leak, you're just not providing enough memory to your Java process.